# JavaFX 14, Stacked Bar chart does not display negative values

Tags: java, javafx, charts, openjfx

**Example:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.StackedBarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    // Start the javafx application
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

        XYChart.Series<String, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(0 + "", 5));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(1 + "", -5));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(2 + "", 3));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(3 + "", -2));

        StackedBarChart<String, Number> weightChangeChartBar = new StackedBarChart<String, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
        weightChangeChartBar.getData().addAll(series);

        Scene scene = new Scene(weightChangeChartBar, 500, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

**Outcome:**

[image: Outcome]

None of the previous stack overflow questions on this issue are working in JavaFX14 (for me anyway), does anyone know of a solution?

Previous Questions:

1. [JavaFX:13 Stacked Bar Chart negative values not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58426539/javafx13-stacked-bar-chart-negative-values-not-showing)
2. [JavaFx StackedBar Chart Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410153/javafx-stackedbar-chart-issue)
3. [Javafx StackedBarChart bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355323/javafx-stackedbarchart-bug)

Answer (score 1):

**Solved it:** 
The Bar Charts behavior must be overridden to solve the bug, the series must be added to the Bar Chart, THEN data can be added to the series.

```
 package example;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Node;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
    import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
    import javafx.scene.chart.StackedBarChart;
    import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class Main extends Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

        // Start the javafx application
        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) {

            CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
            NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

            XYChart.Series<String, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();

             // modify behavior to counter bug
             StackedBarChart<String, Number> barChart = new StackedBarChart<String, Number>(xAxis, yAxis) {
                @Override
                protected void dataItemAdded(XYChart.Series<String,Number> series, int itemIndex, XYChart.Data<String,Number> item) {
                    super.dataItemAdded(series, itemIndex, item);

                    Node bar = item.getNode();
                    double barVal = item.getYValue().doubleValue();

                    if (barVal < 0) {
                        bar.getStyleClass().add("negative");
                    }   
                }       
            };

            // add series
            barChart.getData().addAll(series);

            // THEN add data
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(0 + "", 5));
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(1 + "", -5));
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(2 + "", 3));
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(3 + "", -2));


            Scene scene = new Scene(barChart, 500, 500);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        }

    }
```

Negative nodes must also have separate CSS from the positive nodes.

```
/* ====== BAR CHART =========================================================== */
/* TODO flip gradient vertical for negative bars */
.chart-bar {
    -fx-bar-fill: #22bad9;
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(derive(-fx-bar-fill,-30%), derive(-fx-bar-fill,-40%)),
                          linear-gradient(derive(-fx-bar-fill,80%), derive(-fx-bar-fill, 0%)),
                          linear-gradient(derive(-fx-bar-fill,30%), derive(-fx-bar-fill,-10%));
    -fx-background-insets: 0,1,2;
    -fx-background-radius: 5 5 0 0, 4 4 0 0, 3 3 0 0;
}

.negative.chart-bar {
   -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to top, derive(-fx-bar-fill,-30%), derive(-fx-bar-fill,-40%)),
                          linear-gradient(to top, derive(-fx-bar-fill, 80%), derive(-fx-bar-fill,0%)),
                          linear-gradient(to top, derive(-fx-bar-fill,30%), derive(-fx-bar-fill,-10%));
   -fx-background-radius: 0 0 5 5, 0 0 4 4, 0 0 3 3;
}
.bar-chart:horizontal .chart-bar, .stacked-bar-chart:horizontal .chart-bar {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to left, derive(-fx-bar-fill,-30%), derive(-fx-bar-fill,-40%)),
                          linear-gradient(to left, derive(-fx-bar-fill,80%), derive(-fx-bar-fill, 0%)),
                          linear-gradient(to left, derive(-fx-bar-fill,30%), derive(-fx-bar-fill,-10%));
    -fx-background-radius: 0 5 5 0, 0 4 4 0, 0 3 3 0;
}
.bar-chart:horizontal .negative.chart-bar, .stacked-bar-chart:horizontal .negative.chart-bar {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to right, derive(-fx-bar-fill,-30%), derive(-fx-bar-fill,-40%)),
                          linear-gradient(to right, derive(-fx-bar-fill, 80%), derive(-fx-bar-fill, 0%)),
                          linear-gradient(to right, derive(-fx-bar-fill,30%), derive(-fx-bar-fill,-10%));
    -fx-background-radius: 5 0 0 5, 4 0 0 4, 3 0 0 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The patch in [wyit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61014860/6595777) didn't work for me, but it led me in the right direction; I had to override a different method in StackedBarChart.

The official implementation ([GitHub](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/chart/StackedBarChart.java#L256)) uses `bar.getStyleClass().setAll()`, which removes the `negative` CSS class from the bar, resulting in incorrect rendering.

The following Java class patches the problematic method in StackedBarChart.

```java
/**
 * Fixes StackedBarChart can't display negative numbers.
 */
public class PatchedStackedBarChart<X, Y> extends StackedBarChart<X, Y> {
    public PatchedStackedBarChart(@NamedArg("xAxis") Axis<X> xAxis, @NamedArg("yAxis") Axis<Y> yAxis) {
        super(xAxis, yAxis);
    }

    /**
     * Override the method that breaks the graph, patch to add missing "negative" CSS class.
     */
    @Override
    protected void dataItemAdded(Series<X, Y> series, int itemIndex, Data<X, Y> item) {
        super.dataItemAdded(series, itemIndex, item);

        Number val = (Number) (item.getYValue() instanceof Number ? item.getYValue() : item.getXValue());
        if (val.doubleValue() < 0) {
            // add missing CSS class
            item.getNode().getStyleClass().add("negative");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Override the method that breaks the graph, patch so it doesn't override styles.
     */
    @Override
    protected void seriesChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Series> c) {
        for (int i = 0; i < getData().size(); i++) {
            List<Data<X, Y>> items = getData().get(i).getData();
            for (int j = 0; j < items.size(); j++) {
                Node bar = items.get(j).getNode();
                // change .setAll to .addAll to avoid overriding styles
                bar.getStyleClass().removeIf(s -> s.matches("chart-bar|(series|data)\\d+"));
                bar.getStyleClass().addAll("chart-bar", "series" + i, "data" + j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```